# Проблема с сохранением файла

Tags: python, строки, файлы

Здравствуйте. Не понимаю в чем заключается ошибка?

```
for element in NodeName:
    ListSite.write(''.join(element2[i].getAttribute('org') + '\t' +
               element.getElementsByTagName('ip')[0].childNodes[0] + '\t' +
               element.getElementsByTagName('domain')[0].childNodes[0] + '\t' +
               element.getElementsByTagName('url')[0].childNodes[0]'\t'+ 
               '\n').encode('cp1251'));
    i += 1;
```

Компилятор ругается вот так:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need
> string or buffer, instance found

Я попробовал перевести сперва всё в `str()`, но ошибка остается, пробовал открывать файл с параметром `bufering=-1`, также указывал кодировку для открытия файла в 'utf-8'. Всё, что находил в гугле, то и пробовал. Но, что то у меня не получается.

Comment: Предпоследняя строка:
`.encode('cp1251')` ==>  `.encode('utf-8')`
???

Comment: @samoilow, разницы нет, что с cp1251, что с utf-8 одинакого реагирует

Comment: Можно глянуть как открываете файл?

Comment: @WorldCount, конечно ListSite = open(INPUT_DIR + NEW_RESOURCE, 'wb');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какая версия python?

join у вас для каких целей?

```
#Test1
a = "One"
b = "Two"
c = ''.join((a, b))
print c
>>> OneTwo

#Test2
a = "One"
b = "Two"
c = a + b
print c
>>> OneTwo
```

join в качестве параметра принимает итерируемый объект, т.е.:

```
print '-'.join("ups")
>>> u-p-s
```

**Upd.**

Просто вы сперва склеиваете строку так:

```
elem1 + '\t' + elem2 + '\t' + elem3 + '\t' + elem4 + '\t'+ '\n'
```

А потом склеиваете эту же строку, но уже по-символьно:

```
''.join("Тут уже склеенная вами строка")
```

Т.е. лишнюю работу выполняете.

По-хорошему, надо так:

```
''.join((elem1, '\t', elem2, '\t', elem3, '\t', elem4, '\t\n'))
```

Получится строка:

```
elem1    elem2    elem3     elem4   [переход на новую строчку]
```

Comment: ''.join() я на просторах гугла нашел, что так нужно делать, версию использую 2.7.

Comment: @WorldCount, я пробую перевести каждый элемент в str(), и у меня выскакивает известная ошибка
>UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in >position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: А файл из которого получаете данные в какой кодировке идет?

Comment: @WorldCount, вот же я дурак) я пробовал все, кроме 
> str().encode('cp1251') 
Спасибо вам огромное, я бы так дальше и тупил бы)

Comment: @artemiy рад если смог помочь.